# How do I combine String with each comma separated value from another Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, string, equations

I am working with a list of account numbers in column A and list of subs in column B. Column A has just the account number for example: 310050. Column B has a list of subs: Example: 10,11,30. What I am trying to do is create an equation for column C to spit out 31005010,31005011,31005030 but everything I am researching is only showing how to split commas into rows or columns. How would you guys resolve this?
[Current Excel Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpBxB.png)

Comment: @Yass this question was already resolved by Scott. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a subscription for Office 365 Excel, use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

If you do not have a subscrition then you can put this code in a module attached to the workbook.  Then you would use the formula as described above.

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I do have office 365 but it seems there was a small misunderstanding. Cell B1 is 10,11,30. I will attach a screen shot to the original question

Comment: @Ardel see edit, remember that if it works mark it as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: I have both typed it in and copy / pasted and it is giving me #Name? error. I am digging through it now to see if I can find what error I made. I did use CTRL + shift + enter and it did put the { } around it.

Comment: Then you do not have the subscription to 365 or you have not updated it.  The code needs to go in a module attached to the workbook, not the worksheet code or ThisWorkbook code.

Comment: That's it! This is great man, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In case when the function `TEXTJOIN` is unavailable
and `UDF` solution is not desirable for some reason,
this worksheet formula will help in this case:

```
=SUBSTITUTE("@"&SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",",@"),"@",A1)
```

, assuming that symbol `@` is not used in the data,
otherwise use any other unused symbol instead.

[image]